# What happens if I decline a Steam gift?

Tags: steam

My friend has just sent me a gift for Christmas on Steam, but I already have a copy of it.
I want to know what will happen if I decline the gift. Will my friend be able to get a refund on it, or will he just have the game himself?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A declined gift [will be returned](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#gifts-use) to the [owner's gift inventory](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#gifts-sent), from where it can be gifted again.

Valve generally does *not* grant refunds in this case, as Steam [already tells the user](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#own) if the gift target already owns the game.

Comment: Can you gift someone else the gift?

Comment: @WernerCD I'm not sure if I understand you correctly - if you're asking whether the original owner (that is, the person who tried to send the gift) can send it to someone else, then, yes that is possible.

Comment: No... Person A buys... gifts to Person B... B already owns game (or doesn't want). Can person B gift to person C?

Comment: And, on topic... the original person can see who has or hasn't accepted given gifts and can recall and send to someone else if they haven't been claimed yet.

Comment: @WernerCD I believe you can choose to add the gift to your own inventory (rather than redeeming it) after you accept the gift. At least that's what I remember from two days ago, but I wasn't really paying attention.

Comment: @Bob That is true indeed. These things are all explained on the page I linked to, though, and rather unrelated to the question at hand.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete due to Valve's new refund policy.

Answer (score 10):

Generally, if you decline a gift, [it will be deleted, and the sender will **automatically receive a refund**.](https://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/1301948399254001159)

The sender will receive a notification like this:

[image: Gift refunded: "We've automatically initiated a refund for the purchase of the gift."]

---

However, if the gift was sent from the sender's gift inventory, it will not be refunded, and instead just remain there. It can be re-gifted or redeemed at will.

Since May 4th 2017, it is **no longer possible** to add games to your inventory, but pre-existing gift copies can still be sent this way.

[image: Gift returned to inventory: "Your gift has been returned to your Gift Inventory."]

Comment: As of July 2023 this is still the current process, although I didn't receive a notification in Steam (yet?), but did receive an email.

Answer (score 6):

If you decline the game (or any gift) it will just return back to the senders inventory.  From there, they can send/trade it with someone else.